# How do you set the heading of the map?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, camera, mapbox

I am using Mapbox, and I am trying to follow the user during the users movements thrue the map. But how do I make the camera turn in the same direction as the user does in real life?

```
//Create a new MKMapCamera object
    let newCameraPosition = MGLMapCamera(lookingAtCenterCoordinate: mapView.centerCoordinate, fromDistance: mapView.camera.altitude + 65, pitch: 70, heading: 0)

    // Then you could call it like this
    mapView.camera = newCameraPosition

    // Track users location
    self.mapView.setUserTrackingMode(MGLUserTrackingMode.Follow, animated: true);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're most of the way there: use [`MGLUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading`](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.3.4/Enums/MGLUserTrackingMode.html#/c:@E@MGLUserTrackingMode@MGLUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading) (`.FollowWithHeading`).

Comment: Thanks alot friedbunny!